# Oracle DB 21c, Index not getting picked up when querying JSON data

Tags: json, oracle

I have a table "orders" that contains several thousand rows.  The table has a CLOB column that contains a JSON payload.  Each row in the table is for a single order and the JSON contains the order details (orderid, site_name, order total etc).

I create an index on the table as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX orders_sitename_idx ON
     orders ( JSON_VALUE(
        json_document, '$.site_name' RETURNING VARCHAR2 ERROR ON ERROR) );
```

The index created OK but when I run the following query I see that the index is not used (explain plan shows full table scan).

```
SELECT
    d.site_name,
    d.orderid
FROM
    orders ct,
    JSON_TABLE ( ct.json_document, '$'
            COLUMNS 
                site_name VARCHAR2 PATH '$.site_name',
                orderid NUMBER PATH '$.order.orderid'            
        ) d
    where site_name = 'My Site';
```

Any pointers as to why the index is not being used?

I have tried playing around with the query and index (really to make sure there is no issue with data types) but no joy.

Comment: Please post you query execution plan. It is not reproducible even on empty table, see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sflY8bR_)

Comment: If you create a standard function index on a JSON_VALUE expression there is no chance ORACLE will use it to help a JSON_TABLE one. What you may want to investigate is the usage of a JSON search index which is an Oracle Text (full-text) index designed specifically for use with JSON data. (create search index index_name on table(column) for json)

Comment: @p3consulting [JSON Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/indexes-for-json-data.html#GUID-7CEAFFC2-C7B8-4223-BAD9-870858990939): *An index created using json_value with ERROR ON ERROR **can be used** for a query involving `json_table`, if the WHERE clause refers to a column projected by json_table, and the effective SQL/JSON path that targets that column matches the indexed path expression.*

Comment: good to know, but if the problem is not related to cardinality, check that you have a constraint IS JSON on your CLOB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table is small or the table's statistics are stale, the SQL optimizer may decide that it is more efficient to do the table scan than to use the index. Try updating the table's statistics and see if that makes a difference.

> This example uses the DBMS_STATS package to gather statistics on the
> sh.customers table with a parallelism setting of 2.
>
> ```
> BEGIN
>   DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS (  
>     ownname => 'sh'
> ,   tabname => 'customers'
> ,   degree  => 2  
> );
> END;
> /
> ```

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/tgsql/gathering-optimizer-statistics.html#GUID-5AC92747-F6AA-4149-80B6-FD6E966CDC8D